# Can I join Asar with Zuhr according to Shi'ite jurisprudence?

Tags: salat, shiism, prayer-timings

I work in an IT firm and my duty period is usually 8-5. My office is about 50km's away from my home. I get my lunch break at 1.00 PM so I can pray Zuhr without any problems. But since I usually work till 5 and I need to run to catch the train home (otherwise I miss Maghrib too) straight from work, I miss Asar. My mother told me to pray Asar along with Zuhr (8 rakah's without giving salam at the end of Zuhr salah). Is it possible for me to do that?

I know the best solution is to go to mosque after work and pray Asar. But if I do that, I'll have to wait till 6.30 PM and pray Maghrib and then return home (which means it'll be past 9.00 PM when I get home.) I just want to know if I can do what my mom said.

I am particularly interested in an answer according to Shi'ite jurisprudence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Shia view

Yes you can join them. But joining does not mean without Salam. but means without a lot of time between two prayers.

> We are allowed to pray noon and afternoon prayer one after another
>   (without a lot of delay between the two). Similarly we are allowed to
>   pray sunset prayer and night prayer one after another.
>
> Actually it is better to pray in their own specific time (close to
>   what Sunnis do), but it is not necessary. Thus instead of five
>   separate times, we can pray all the five daily prayers only in three
>   separate times.

**Reference and more information:**

[Joining Prayers and Other related Issues](http://www.al-islam.org/shiite-encyclopedia-ahlul-bayt-dilp-team/joining-prayers-and-other-related-issues)

Comment: "to pray in their own specific time (close to what Sunnis do)", AFAIK this is not very true, the best way for doing the Dhuhr and Asar prayer according to Ayatullah Bahjat is to do the Nafilah of Dhuhur right after Adhan Dhuhur, then the Dhuhur Salah itself, then the Nafilah of Asar right after the Dhuhur Salah and its following Dua and Dhikr, then right after that the Asar Salah. It can be far sooner that the Sunni brothers do pray Asar prayer. However, about the night prayer yes it is better to wait until the darkness settles, although not necessarily.

Comment: Also you may like to complete your answer by explaining four different time each obligatory Salah has: First. period of time for praying being Adaa` (وقت الصلوة), Second. the beginning of the praying time (اول الوقت), Third. the period of time in which praying has more rewards (وقت الفضیلة), Fourth. the specific period of time for each Salah (وقت مخصوصه).